# Compiler error for conditional operator "?:" when used with typecasting operator

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, conditional-operator, typecasting-operator

Following code is in simplest form:

```
struct X {
  operator char () const { return 'a'; }
};

int main ()
{
  X obj, *p = &obj;
  char a = *p;  // ok
  char c = (true)? *p : 'z';
}
```

[This code](http://www.ideone.com/lUJE2) gives compiler error as,

> error: operands to ?: have different types ‘X’ and ‘char’

Why `*p` is not resolved to `char` when there is no ambiguity in `class X` for typecasting operator ?
Is such **spurious error message** correct or it's a g++ bug ?

[**Update** Note: Interestingly [this scenario doesn't generate such error](http://www.ideone.com/Q8JEH)]

Comment: I build it with g++ 4.4.5, with flags -Wall and -Wextra, and get no errors or warnings.

Comment: Which compiler produces this error? Works fine on g++ 4.6.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be a compiler-bug. I checked it out in the spec, the Standard clearly says (§5.16/3 - C++03),

> Otherwise, if the second and third operand have different types, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, **an attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the other**.

and the rest of the section explains how the conversion is done. There is nothing that stops `*p` from implicitly converting into `char` type, using the user-defined conversion operator.

Also, I compiled it with `(GCC) 4.5.0`. It gives no error, with `-pedantic` option as well. Tried it `-std=c++98` and `-std=c++0x`. Still no error.

Most definitely, it is a compiler-bug.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler then evaluate `*p` or `'z'` according to the result type? Or is there something else that I might be missing?

Comment: Wow... C++ can sure surprise you sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

There are issues with implicit conversion between classes for the conditional operator ?: in certain versions of G++.  Also depending on the version you may either see an error, or you may /not/ see such an errors, *however all three of your samples are correctly flagged by G++*.

This is less of an answer to the original question but a re-certification of the original poster's, and others', qualm that there might be problems with spurious errors with G++ compiler and the conversion behavior for class types as specified in ISOC++:2003 5.16/3 [expr.cond]/3 (also outlined above by @Nawaz)

One example that shows the converse of the original poster's sample where implicit conversion in both directions can happen but isn't flagged can be seen [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=32019).

I compiled this on G++ v3.4.6, v4.1.2, v4.2.1 and v4.5.0(windows) and saw no problems because as again @Nawaz said this is the correct behavior within the ISOC++:2003 spec.

However, when I followed the link on your [IDEONE](http://www.ideone.com/lUJE2) page the structure definition was different and **that** is the root of your error.

```
struct X
{
  char ch;
  X(const char c) : ch(c) {}

  operator char () const { return ch; }
};

int main ()
{
  X obj('a'), *p = &obj;
  char a = *p; // ok
  char c = (true)? *p : 'b';
}
```

Then as above the struct is different and I do get the error your see.  **This is a correct error as 'z' can be converted into X or char, and because of the constructor 'z' can also be converted into X - bi-directionality of X/'z' so the compiler should stop.**   However with a little change it can be made to pass and that is exactly the same bug as the GNU G++ bug posted above.

If you convert your sample above to a pointer sample it will fail.  Character pointer, int pointer or whatever.

Although unrelated I thought it might be a good point to highlight something that often caught me out whilst cross-porting between Windows/Linux.  MSVC will happily pass such conversions often if it deems the conversion to be "safe", or often it may proffer a warning that conversion is being done at the risk of loss of precision - I am not sure what the trigger for allowing this is.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. operands to `?:` have different types: ‘X’ the first, and ‘char’ the second. The compiler cannot know that you want the expression to be a char in the end - that will happen later, after the evaluation of the whole expression `(true)? *p : 'z';` - an evaluation which cannot be done in the first place due to type discrepancies.